# When would you use a key-value pair over a dict for the dict.update method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've noticed that you can do two things to update a dictionary, and that they seem to have the same outcome:

```
a = {}
a.update({'foo': 1})

a = {}
a.update(foo = 1)
```

Both lead to the result of a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'foo': 1}
```

Is there any reason to prefer using a dictionary or a key/value pair for the update method? Are they completely functionally equivalent or is there a 'gotcha' that one syntax might cause?

Comment: One difference is that when you use named keywords you can only update keys which are valid python names. For updating any other keys like integers, tuples, strings which aren't valid python names you would need to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any reason to prefer using a dictionary or a key/value pair for the update method?

That you already have one, e.g. if you have a base dict and an other dict (from a constant, or a parameter) then `dict1.update(dict2)` makes perfect sense.

Also makes sense if you're generating the second dict dynamically e.g. `dict1.update(zip(keys, values))`.

> Are they completely functionally equivalent or is there a 'gotcha' that one syntax might cause?

The "keyword arguments" form only works with string keys (in Python 3, in Python 2 it unintentionally worked with non-string keys as well). Even using the mapping-unpacking form. It also can not be used with literal keywords e.g.

```
d.update(assert=3)
```

is a syntax error.

More generally

### The keyword form is useless on its own

It can make sense to add keywords to an `update` call with a positional argument e.g.

```py
d.update(d2, key=value)
```

as you're already piggybacking on a call which is necessary. However

```py
d.update(key=value)
```

is generally[0] just a more complicated, more limiting, *and slower* way of writing

````py
d['key'] = value
```:
```sh
❯ python3 -mtimeit -s "d = {'a': 'b'}" "d.update(c='d', e='f', g='h')"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 202 nsec per loop
❯ python3 -mtimeit -s "d = {'a': 'b'}" "d['c']='d'; d['e']='f'; d['g']='h'"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 62.2 nsec per loop
````

I don't remember the numbers (and they probably changed with recent releases as there have been optimisations to literal dicts) but when I benched this a few years back you'd need several dozen keys before you broke even.

[0] it can be useful in the *rare* case where you need to update a dict in an expression context e.g. a lambda body, I don't think I've ever been in that situation

Comment: "using dict.update (either form) with a static and low number of kvs is just dumb." What about if you have a function which populates a dict with a bunch of different keys depending on certain conditions? E.g. `if a == 1: d.update(foo = 1)` `elif a == 2: d.update(bar = 1)`. You could populate the dict with `d = {foo = 0, bar = 0}` before you get to those assignments I guess, but wouldn't that be trading speed for memory in situations with larger dicts?

Comment: This example makes no sense, it's a more complicated *and* slower version of `if a == 1: d['foo'] = 1; elif a == 2: d['bar'] = 1`.

Answer (score 3):

There could be different reasons for using one over the other. For example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(a=2)        # looks much cleaner
>>> d.update({'a': 2})   # We need to unnecessarily write a few more characters,
```

But then again, if I want to update a key other than of str type:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(2='a')      # Gives a syntax error
>>> d.update({2: 'a'})   # is the only way
```

Furthermore, you can store a `dict`, so if you needed to update via a variable:

```
>>> u = {'a': 2}
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(u)          # clean
>>> d.update(**u)        # Essentially same as using keyword argument form, but unnecessary
```

Another scenario, when you are updating some key manually, but others from a variable, keyword argument form is cleaner and shorter:

```
>>> u = {'a': 2}
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(b=3, **u)
# Whereas to use `dict` form:
>>> d.update({'b': 3, **u})   # Introduces unnecessary clutter
```

Comment: I agree that the key-value method is much cleaner and nicer to look at. I was just wondering if there are any issues that come up from doing it. I guess so long as the key that I wish to use isn't a reserved word like 'list' or 'dict' or something, and so long as it will evaluate to a string, it should be completely fine?

Comment: `list` and `dict` are not reserved words. `def` or `class` are.

Comment: You can update with any string that will be a valid variable name in python.